# Как отключить работу функциональных клавиш без Fn?

Tags: linux, клавиатура, archlinux, gnome

Установил Arch Linux с окружением GNOME, и не могу разобраться как отключить работу клавиш f1-f12 без зажатой Fn. Проблема вряд ли в настройках BIOS, рядом стоит другая ОС, где все работает как надо. Пробовал переназначить сочетания клавиш вручную, однако новые сочетания клавиш просто добавляются к обычному нажатию f1-f12. Сбрасывал настройки клавиатуры к заводским - тоже не помогло.

Comment: Обычно обработка `Fn` полностью на совести контроллера клавиатуры/фирмвари ноутбука... Если оно и предоставляет какой-то программный доступ к контролю его состояния на уровень ОС, то скорей всего решение будет специфично для конкретного устройства... ЗЫ: и гугл говорит, что Fn Lock обычно переключается через `Fn+Esc`

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, я смотрел документацию к клавиатуре перед тем, как писать сюда, но не смог найти что-либо способное помочь мне. Fn Lock не совсем то, что мне нужно, поскольку `Fn` работает на аппаратном уровне, проверил в стоящей по соседству ОС. В самой клаве ничего не залочено.

Comment: гм... не совсем понимаю твою ситуацию... сейчас у тебя при нажатии на `F1-12` посылаются мультимедийные клавиши, а при `Fn+F1-12` — собственно `F1-12`, а ты хочешь сделать чтоб было наоборот, верно? и в «соседней ОС» это по умолчанию наоборот, так? как я понимаю, «текущая ситуация» и подразумевается под «включённым Fn Lock»... и что `xev` говорит о событиях нажатия клавиш?

Comment: @Fat-Zer `xev` не ловит события при нажатии `Fn` и `F1-F12`. `Fn` события вообще утилиты почему-то не отображают. `F1-F12` и `Fn+F1-F12` посылают мультимедийные события. Но клавиатура нормально обрабатывает свои встроенные комбинации содержащие `Fn`, и в другой ОС `Fn+F1-F12` - мультемедийка, `F1-F12` - открытие кода в браузере, полноэкранный режим и т.д. Причем я не видел информацию что `Fn` нужно включать где бы то ни было в ОС...

Comment: я так и не понял, «и `F1-F12`, и `Fn+F1-F12` посылают мультимедийные события» или «`F1-F12` не посылают события вообще»? ЗЫ: в любом случае странно всё это...

Comment: @Fat-Zer оба варианта посылают мультимедийные события, но они не отображаются в `xev`

Comment: гммм... странно это... извини, у меня идеи пока кончились... можно, разве что, проверить, что в `showkey` такое же поведение, как и в `xev` — если такое же, то проблема где-то между драйвером и устройством... если разное, то проблема где-то между X'ами и ядром...